# Accessing documents on a http server running in a virtual machine

Tags: centos, virtual-machine

I run Windows 7 as my main OS, and for development work I installed CentOS on a virtual machine under VirtualBox. Everything is installed, including httpd and php with mysql, but I can't figure out what IP to use to gain access to the server.

For example, I used to have XAMPP installed on 7 and I just used "localhost" to get to the servers document root, but I have no clue what it is for the virtual machine.

I have tried "locahost", "192.168.11.2" (my address on the network) and my own IP address and I can't seem to get it working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know VirtualBox, but can you do an ifconfig from the terminal window to your VM.  If it doesn't give you a terminal window, your CentOS setup probably does DHCP to get an address.  Browse to the web interface of your home router (192.168.11.1?) and check the DHCP clients table to see if it registered and get its address.